# Can't figure out how to get the game to stop when a player scores 5 points.

Tags: java, class, while-loop

I have a game that simulates two players flipping a coin and guessing heads or tails. The game is suppose to stop when the first player gets 5 points. I have tried a while statement but it doesn't stop till both are over 5. New to programming and could use a fresh set of eyes with more knowledge than me. Thank you all for any help. (look at the code starting at //play the game.)

```
/**
 * This program demonstrates the coin class
 * and plays a game between two players.
 */

public class CoinGame 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
       {
          final int maxPoints = 5;  // Number of rounds
          String player1Name;        // First player's name
          String player2Name;        // Second player's name

          // Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
          Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

          // Get the player's names.
          System.out.print("Enter the first player's name: ");
          player1Name = keyboard.nextLine();
          System.out.print("Enter the second player's name: ");
          player2Name = keyboard.nextLine();

          // Create the coin.
          Coin coin = new Coin();

          // Create the two players.
          Player player1 = new Player(player1Name);
          Player player2 = new Player(player2Name);

          // Play the game.
          while (player1.getPoints() <= maxPoints || player2.getPoints() <= maxPoints)
          {
             System.out.println("----------------------------");
            // System.out.printf("Now playing round %d.\n", round + 1);

             // Flip the coin.
             coin.toss();

             // The players make their guesses.
             player1.makeGuess();
             player2.makeGuess();

             // Determine the winner of this round.
             roundResults(coin, player1, player2);
          }

          // Display the grand winner.
          displayGrandWinner(player1, player2);
       }

       /**
        *  The roundResults method determines the results of
        *  the current round. The parameters are:
        *  coin: The Coin object
        *  player1: Player #1 object
        *  player2: Player #2 object
        */

       public static void roundResults(Coin coin, Player player1,
                                       Player player2)
       {
          // Show the coin side.
          /*System.out.printf("The coin turned up %d.\n",
                            coin.getSideUp());
                */            
          System.out.printf("The coin turned up: %s\n", coin.getSideUp());

          // Check each player's guess and award points.
          checkGuess(player1, coin);
          checkGuess(player2, coin);
       }

       /**
        *  The checkGuess method checks a player's guess against
        *  the coin's result. The parameters are:
        *  player: The Player object to check.
        *  coin: The Coin object.
        */

       public static void checkGuess(Player player, Coin coin)
       {
          final int POINTS_TO_ADD = 1; // Points to award winner
          String guess = player.getGuess();           // Player's guess
          String coinResult = coin.getSideUp(); // Heads or Tails

          // Display the player's guess.
          System.out.printf("The player %s guessed %s.\n", 
                            player.getName(), player.getGuess());

          // Award points if the player guessed correctly.
          if (guess.equalsIgnoreCase(coinResult))
          {
             player.addPoints(POINTS_TO_ADD);
             System.out.printf("Awarding %d point(s) to %s.\n",
                               POINTS_TO_ADD, player.getName());
          }
       }

       /**
         *  The displayGrandWinner method displays the game's grand winner.
         *  The parameters are:
         *  player1: Player #1
         *  player2: Player #2
        */

       public static void displayGrandWinner(Player player1, Player player2)
       {
          System.out.println("----------------------------");
          System.out.println("Game over. Here are the results:");
          System.out.printf("%s: %d points.\n", player1.getName(), 
                            player1.getPoints());
          System.out.printf("%s: %d points.\n", player2.getName(),
                            player2.getPoints());

          if (player1.getPoints() > player2.getPoints())
             System.out.println(player1.getName() + " is the grand winner!");
          else if (player2.getPoints() > player1.getPoints())
             System.out.println(player2.getName() + " is the grand winner!");
          else
             System.out.println("Both players are tied!");
       }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
while (player1.getPoints() <= maxPoints || player2.getPoints() <= maxPoints)
```

to

```
while (player1.getPoints() <= maxPoints && player2.getPoints() <= maxPoints)
```

Comment: Thank you, that was it. I also had to remove the = so it would stop at 5.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop:

```
while (player1.getPoints() <= maxPoints || player2.getPoints() <= maxPoints)
```

should instead be:

```
while (player1.getPoints() <= maxPoints && player2.getPoints() <= maxPoints)
```

The reason for this is the `||` means that the while loop will not exit unless BOTH players are greater than 5, instead of one-of. Changing it to `&&` means that the loop is only executed while both are true.